# Convert a String which include letter and number to int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm doing the part of data analysis, but the Id of item export from MongoDB, so the id is the objectid and the value of id include letter and number:

```
'5affb8f318ec0f0024abe3a1'
'59f70ac42706222d006f28cf'
..................
```

But I need to transform them as a float or int. Is there any way can easily implement?

for example:

```
'5affb8f318ec0f0024abe3a1' -> 0
'59f70ac42706222d006f28cf' -> 1
.........................  -> 2
```

Comment: `pd.factorize(df.yourcolumn)[0]`

Comment: You mean you just want an autoincrementing index?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the example and what you mean by "id is the objectid and the value of id include letter and number?" It's not clear at all what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pandas`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html

```
id = pd.factorize('5affb8f318ec0f0024abe3a1')[0]
```

You could also just make a list, I guess if you wanted to.

```
list_of_item = ['5affb8f318ec0f0024abe3a1', '59f70ac42706222d006f28cf']
id = list_of_item.index('5affb8f318ec0f0024abe3a1')
print(id)

>> 0
```